# Calculating average for each row of a filtered dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have a dataframe like this

```
    HomeTeam    AwayTeam     HomeGol    AwayGol
0   U. De Chile  Everton           0    1
1   Huachipato   Colo Colo         0    2
2   Melipilla    Antofagasta       1    1
3   U. Espanola  U. Catolica       3    2
4   S. Wanderers O'Higgins         0    0
... ... ... ... ...
57  Palestino    Antofagasta       2    4
58  U. Espanola  S. Wanderers      3    1
59  Colo Colo    Union La Calera   0    0
60  Everton      O'Higgins         1    1
61  Curico Unido Melipilla         2    0
```

I have to filter by the team that played at Home, Away and both. Then calculate the average goal of last matches, for each teams in rows. In the last `append` new columns to the original dataframe.
For the first team, filtered Dataframes will be, Expected Result when team played at home:

```
    HomeTeam    AwayTeam    HomeGol AwayGol AverageG_Team_plays_home    AverageG_Team_plays_away    AverageG_Team_plays_both
0   U. De Chile Everton            0    1   1.333333    NaN NaN
1   U. De Chile S. Wanderers       1    0   1.500000    NaN NaN
2   U. De Chile U. Espanola        2    1   1.000000    NaN NaN
3   U. De Chile Huachipato         1    1   0.000000    NaN NaN
```

Expected Result when team played away:

```
    HomeTeam    AwayTeam    HomeGol AwayGol AverageG_Team_plays _at_away
0   Antofagasta U. De Chile       1       2     0
1   Colo Colo   U. De Chile       1       0     0
2   La Serena   U. De Chile       0       0     0
```

Expected Result when team played both:

```
    HomeTeam    AwayTeam    HomeGol AwayGol AverageG_Team_plays_at_both_home AverageG_Team_plays_at_both_away
0   U. De Chile Everton        0        1    1.00
1   Antofagasta U. De Chile    1        2            0.80
2   U. De Chile S. Wanderers   1        0    0.75
3   Colo Colo   U. De Chile    1        0            1.00
4   U. De Chile U. Espanola    2        1    0.50
5   La Serena   U. De Chile    0        0            1.00
6   U. De Chile Huachipato     1        1    0.00
```

Tried this code, but does not calculate from the previous match, does not iterate for all rows and does not add result to new columns

```
homeGroup = df.groupby('HomeTeam')
awayGroup = df.groupby('AwayTeam')

homelastgame = homeGroup['Datetime'].max()
awaylastgame = awayGroup['Datetime'].max()
teamlastgame = pd.concat([homelastgame, awaylastgame]).reset_index().groupby('index')['Datetime'].max()
print(teamlastgame)

homeavscore = homeGroup['HomeGol'].mean()
awayavscore = awayGroup['AwayGol'].mean()
teamAveScore = (homeGroup['HomeGol'].sum() + awayGroup['AwayGol'].sum()) / (homeGroup['HomeGol'].count() + awayGroup['AwayGol'].count()) 
print(teamAveScore)
```